# Unable to properly read the lines from a file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, file, file-io

I have file, which i wrote using a `python script`. The file is large and contain more than a 1000 lines, and each line is very large and it goes like :(shortened)

```
1 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
2 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
3 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
...
```

And see, each line could take the space of 3 lines while displaying it in the monitor.
When I try :

```
fp = open('data.txt','r')
c = 0
for line in fp:
    c += 1
print("No. of line = ",c)
```

I get the correct value, and when I use the `read()` function, I get a different value, as in:

```
fp = open('data.txt','r')
c = 0
data = fp.read()
for line in data:
    c += 1
print("No. of line = ",c)
```

Can somebody explain, what is the difference between using the `read()` function, and not using it ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you have to use `readlines()` instead of `read()`. Second code read all as one string and you for loop get char from this string and you counts chars. First code read by lines and it counts lines.

Comment: BTW: in first `c = len(fp)`, in second `c = len(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
data = fp.read()
for line in data:
    c += 1
```

you read all in one string and `for`-loop treats this string as list of chars - so you count chars.

You have to use `readlines()` to get list of lines and count lines in this list

```
data = fp.readlines()
for line in data:
    c += 1
```

---

BTW: The same result to count chars

```
data = fp.read()
c = len(data)
```

and to count lines

```
data = fp.readlines()
c = len(data)
```

---

BTW: You could also use `print()` to see what you have in variable

```
data = fp.read()
print(data[0])
print(data[:3])
print(data)
```

and

```
data = fp.readlines()
print(data[0])
print(data[:3])
print(data)
```

If you want to test in the one script then you have to close and open fail again or use `fp.seek(0)` to move to beginning of file before you read again.

---

To works with lines you should use

```
fp = open('data.txt','r')

for line in fp:
    # ...code ...

fp.close()
```

or

```
fp = open('data.txt','r')
all_lines = fp.readlines()

for line in all_lines:
    # ...code ...

fp.close()
```

The same with `with ... as ...`

```
with open('data.txt','r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        # ...code ...
```

or

```
with open('data.txt','r') as fp:
    all_lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in all_lines:
        # ...code ...
```