# Python wont read file line by line

Tags: python

```
fh=open('Spam.mbox',encoding='utf-8')
data=fh.read()
for line in data:
    print(line)
```

When I execute the above code, python prints out the data one character at a time instead of line by line.
Please advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using with to open a file and read the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193494/using-with-to-open-a-file-and-read-the-lines)

Comment: if you are not using the `with` statement remember to call the `close()` function on the file, `fh.close()` in your scenario, otherwise the file stays open and this can lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using the `readlines()` function.

```
with open('Spam.mbox',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

With the `data` variable you can iterate over it and print each line

```
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Also, if you don't want to load the whole file in your memory, then you can put the `for` loop inside the `with` statement and do `for line in f: print(line)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you have an idea as to why my code didn't work?

Comment: @durganshtaneja because you used the `read()` function which reads the whole file as a 1 string. the `readlines()` function reads each line as an element of a list.

Answer (score 0):

When reading files use the with statement because then the file will be closed after it has been processed.

Read line by line:

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Read all the lines and then loop through the line:

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f2:
    lines = f2.readlines()
for ln in lines:
    print(ln)
```